# Заполнение и вывод массива

Tags: c

Вроде нормально заполняется массив, меняю два элемента и остальные почему-то повторяются

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
  int mas[19][1], i, j;
  for (i=0; i<20; i++)
      {
      for (j=0; j<2; j++)
          {
          mas[i][j]=rand();
          printf("%d ", mas[i][j]);
          }
       printf("\n");
       }
       mas[10][0]=5;
       mas[10][1]=6;
       printf("\n");
  for (i=0; i<20; i++)
      {
      for (j=0; j<2; j++)
          {
          printf("%d ", mas[i][j]);
          }
       printf("\n");
       }
getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у Вас массив имеет вторую размерность в один элемент. А Вы пытаетесь записать в второй (индексы то ведь с нуля считаются!).

то есть, `mas[10][1]=6;` записывает не совсем туда, куда Вы думаете. И в многих случаях это может привести к неопределенному поведению.